# How to solve an SDE using integration by parts(?)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Context: using this from another thread:
https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/25660/integration-in-the-hull-white-sde

The relevant bit which i am trying to solve is the following part of the thread:
$$\int_t^T e^{\int_0^u b(v) dv} (a(u) du + \sigma(u) dW_u) = \int_t^T a(u) e^{\int_0^u b(v) dv} du + \int_t^T \sigma(u) e^{\int_0^u b(v) dv} dW_u$$ of course with some changes.
My version of the above SDE to solve is:
$$\int_0^t e^{\lambda s} (\theta(s) ds + \sigma dW_s)  = \int_0^t \theta(s) e^{\lambda s} ds + \int_0^t \sigma e^{\lambda s} dW_s$$
But seem to be stuck solving the first integral as it seems to loop into differentiations of $\theta(s)$
$$ \int_0^t \theta(s) e^{\lambda s} ds $$
Is it solvable just by parts or does it have a different approach which I might be missing.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Without knowing what $\theta $ is there is no way to finish.

Comment: Hi I usually try to solve SDE's with Ito' lemma see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma ; maybe it helps^^ and Ian is right!!! more info please

Comment: The equation is a consequence of ito's lemma and so isn't there a general solution for that kind of integral?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do here. The first equation, for instance, seems to just be $\int (\alpha+ \beta)=\int\alpha+\int\beta$ which doesn't say anything new.

Comment: I like the book from Philip E. Protter, Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540003137 ; should stand in any college library there's a lot about solving PDE's

Comment: @Ozooha Ozooha What is your source?

Comment: ok I see: $$\theta=\frac{\sigma^2}{2\lambda}(1-e^{2\lambda s})$$

Comment: @Behrouz this is my link http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/25660/integration-in-the-hull-white-sde

Comment: @Semiclassical stochastic-calculus and stochastic-integrals are irrelevant tags

Comment: @Ozooha Ozooha What is the relation between two questions?

Comment: @ Behrouz Maleki  $$\int_t^T e^{\int_0^u b(v) dv} (a(u) du + \sigma(u) dW_u) = \int_t^T a(u) e^{\int_0^u b(v) dv} du + \int_t^T \sigma(u) e^{\int_0^u b(v) dv} dW_u$$ this portion of the thread is similar to mine with the letters changed